# Creating a sound manager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is how I currently have my Sound Manager setup for a small RPG and I was just wondering if this was good practice.

What I was trying to go for was to have my two methods (PlayBGMusic and PlaySound) to be "public static" so I would not have to grab the GameObject by tag and the Script in almost all of my other scripts that want to play a sound.  If I do make them "public static" then I would have to make my variables the same which takes away from placing anything in the inspector.

```
public class Sound_Manager : MonoBehaviour {
    // Allow the user to decide if music should be on or off.
    public bool backgroundMusicOn;
    // Allow the user to decide if sound should be on or off.
    public bool soundOn;
    // The music volume.
    [Range(0,1)]
    public float musicVolume;
    // The sound volume.
    [Range(0,1)]
    public float soundVolume;
    // The Background music to be used for any manipulations.
    private AudioSource _bgMusic;

// Play a background song.
public void PlayBGMusic(AudioSource music){
...
}

// Mute Current Background Song.
public void MuteUnMuteBGMusic(){
....
}

// Play a sound.
public void PlaySound(AudioClip sfx, Vector3 location){
...
}
}
```

Is this a proper way of handling something like this or is there another way that could be more simple?

Comment: Since advent of [AudioMixer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioMixerOverview) I had no more need to have sound manager in my projects anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend turning the sound manager into a singleton class. In that way you can have all the properties in the inspector and use the singleton object to globally access all your properties, even destroying the gameobject completely when not needed .

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't play BGmusic and sound in one GameObject,because every audio must play whith single audion source,this is my code of AudioManager.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] audioSources;
    public GameObject audioPrefabSource;
    public Dictionary<string,AudioClip> audioClips;
    static GameObject audioPrefab;
    static GameObject instance;
    static AudioSource musicPlayer;
    public static AudioManager audioManager;
    Dictionary<string,Audio> aliveSounds;
    AudioListener al;

    void Awake ()
    {
            audioManager = this;
            al = GetComponent<AudioListener> ();
            audioClips = new Dictionary<string, AudioClip> ();
            foreach (AudioClip a in audioSources) {
                    audioClips.Add (a.name, a);
            }

            instance = this.gameObject;
            audioPrefab = audioPrefabSource;
            musicPlayer = audio;
            aliveSounds = new Dictionary<string, Audio> ();
            //DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
            if (!GameSetting.hasMusic) {
                    musicPlayer.Pause ();
            } else {
                    if (!musicPlayer.isPlaying) {
                            musicPlayer.Play ();
                    }
            }
            if (!GameSetting.hasSound && aliveSounds.Count > 0) {
                    foreach (Audio a in aliveSounds.Values) {
                            a.StopSound ();
                    }
                    aliveSounds.Clear ();
            }
            if (!al.enabled) {
                    al.enabled = true;
            }
    }

    public static void PlaySoundOnce (string name)
    {
            if (!GameSetting.hasSound) {
                    return;
            }
            if (!audioManager.audioClips.ContainsKey (name)) {
                    return;
            }
            GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate (audioPrefab) as GameObject;
            go.transform.parent = instance.transform;
            Audio a = go.GetComponent<Audio> ();
            a.PlaySoundOnce (audioManager.audioClips [name]);
    }


    public static void PlayMusic (string name)
    {
            if (!GameSetting.hasMusic) {
                    return;
            }

            if (musicPlayer.clip == null || musicPlayer.clip.name != name) {
                    //      musicPlayer.clip = audioManager.audioClips [name];
                    musicPlayer.clip = Resources.Load ("Audio/" + name, typeof(AudioClip)) as AudioClip;
                    musicPlayer.Stop ();
                    musicPlayer.loop = true;
                    musicPlayer.Play ();
            } else {
                    musicPlayer.loop = true;
                    musicPlayer.Play ();
            }

    }
}
```

There is another class for Audio,it must be made to a audioprefab.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Audio : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlaySoundOnce (AudioClip audioClip)
    {
            StartCoroutine (PlaySoundCoroutine (audioClip));
    }

    IEnumerator PlaySoundCoroutine (AudioClip audioClip)
    {
            audio.PlayOneShot (audioClip);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (audioClip.length);
            Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    public void PlaySoundLoop (AudioClip audioClip)
    {
            audio.clip = audioClip;
            audio.loop = true;
            audio.Play ();
    }

    public void StopSound ()
    {
            audio.Stop ();
            Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

Like this,and I ignored audio's position,I used 2D sound.

[image]

Comment: you are correct but wont other sources of audio have its own component for the scene that it is in , sound manager should be for background music and simple

Comment: You can play both in one GameObject, in my PlaySound I create a temp gameobject and add a AudioSource to it and destroy via time on how long the sound clip is.